# How can I use Datomic Pro on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, datomic

I'd like to use Datomic Pro (Starter Edition, for now) on Heroku. But I don't want to commit my download key into Git. Instead, the right thing to do would seem to be store it in an environment variable. That means my `project.clj` now contains:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
               [com.datomic/datomic-pro "0.9.4707"]]
:repositories {"my.datomic.com" {:url "https://my.datomic.com/repo"
                                 :username ~(System/getenv "DATOMIC_EMAIL")
                                 :password ~(System/getenv "DATOMIC_KEY")}}
```

I've set `DATOMIC_EMAIL` and `DATOMIC_KEY` in the Heroku app's config. Turns out that doesn't matter, because the `project.clj` is processed during the build phase, without access to the environment variables.

Now that the `user-env-compile` feature no longer exists, how can I get Datomic running on Heroku?

(I could fork the buildpack and force the environment variables to be used during the build phase, but I'd rather avoid going that far if I can.)

Comment: Have you finally succeeded setting-up a Datomic Database on Heroku?

Comment: I have, though I haven't done much with it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you no longer need to fork the buildpack. Heroku recently made changes to their buildpack API that allow buildpacks to see environment vars that you've set for your app.

As described in [Clojure buildpack's README,](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure#configuration) you need to set `BUILD_CONFIG_ALLOWLIST` var to something like this: `DATOMIC_EMAIL DATOMIC_KEY` and also, of course, set `DATOMIC_EMAIL` and `DATOMIC_KEY` vars accordingly.

Hope this helps.