# How to setup Datomic with Heroku Postgresql?

Tags: clojure, heroku-postgres, datomic

I have trouble setting up Datomic with Heroku Postgres. First of all I have this successfully installed

```
[com.datomic/datomic-pro "0.9.5206" :exclusions [joda-time]]
```

My `sql-transactor.properties` file looks like this:

```
protocol=sql
host=localhost
port=4334
license-key=<MY_LICENSE_KEY>
sql-url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-204-3-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/<MY_HEROKU_DB_NAME>
sql-user=<MY_USER>
sql-password=<MY_PASS>
sql-driver-params=ssl=true;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

When I try to run transactor from downloaded datomic-pro folder as:

`bin/transactor /path/to/folder/sql-transactor.properties`

It gives following output:

```
Launching with Java options -server -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50
Starting datomic:sql://<DB-NAME>?jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-204-3-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/<MY_HEROKU_DB_NAME>?user=<MY_USER>&password=<MY_PASS>&ssl=true;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory, you may need to change the user and password parameters to work with your jdbc driver ...

System started datomic:sql://<DB-NAME>?jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-204-3-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/<MY_HEROKU_DB_NAME>?user=<MY_USER>&password=<MY_PASS>&ssl=true;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory, you may need to change the user and password parameters to work with your jdbc driver
```

**NOTE:** The `<DB-NAME>` in the output is literally `<DB-NAME>`. It's not my placeholder. I think this might be a mistake.

Now when I try in clojure:

```
(def uri "datomic:sql://<MY_HEROKU_DB_NAME>?jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<MY_HEROKU_DB_NAME>")

(def conn (datomic.api/connect uri))
```

It gives error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
      org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections., compiling:(server.clj:40:11)
```

Anybody any ideas?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I already did steps from http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html about `bin/sql/postgres-table` script

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Datomic Pro on Heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413176/how-can-i-use-datomic-pro-on-heroku)